# How to put a element in specific location of array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to add a element in specific location of array list For that i tried to initialize the array list with inital capacity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class AddInArrayList{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList list = new ArrayList(4);
  Object obj1 = new Object();
   list.add(1, obj1);
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:359)
        at AddInArrayList.main(AddInArrayList.java:7)

Is  There any way to add a element by specific index location ?

Comment: It does not have any work around .
I need a way to add the element at specific location .

Comment: An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is not an array!

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about the meaning of *[capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html)*: the number you pass to the constructor does **not** set the inital list *size*.

You can't insert an element at index 1 of an empty list because list slots cannot be empty. If you wanted a function that expands the list before inserting at an index greater than its length, you could use:

```
static void addAtPos(List list, int index, Object o) {
    while (list.size() < index) {
        list.add(null);
    } 
    list.add(index, o);
}
```

That said, `ArrayList`s are based on arrays which do not perform well with mid-insertion. So a different data structure will almost certainly be better suited to your problem, but you'd have to let us know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays will not let you to perform insertion at an index which is greater than array.size.

So if you want to associate each item with a number/index it is better to use maps.

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

Object obj1 = new Object();

map.put(1, obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because when you call `add(index, value)`, the value has to be not less than 0 and not bigger than `list.size()-1`. In your case it should be `add(0, obj1)`.

Answer (score 0):

initial capacity will be used only to set the initial "buffer" size of underlying array. so after calling `new ArrayList(4)` you list is still empty.

If you know your List will contain about 10_000 elements, create the ArrayList instance with intial capacity `c = 10_000 + x`. In this way you will avoid expensive `ArrayList#grow(newcapacity)` (Java 8) calls.

The method `ArrayList#add(position, element)` could be also called `ArrayList#addAndMoveOtherToTheRight(position, element)`